Stuck in tty after Ubuntu upgrade from Version 22.04.5 LTS to 24.04
I wanted to upgrade Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04. After starting the upgrading process from my Desktop the PC rebooted but i got an black screen. After one Day i restarted the PC as nothing changed. Since i rebooted the PC i am stuck in tty without an network connection:
(ping 8.8.8.8 -> ping: connect: Network is unreachable).
Additionally for each package i get the message:

package_name< Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>=2.70.0).

I cant reach the GUI with Ctr+Alt+F7
Can someone help with a solution?
